# PHP: count uppercase words in string

Tags: php, count

is there an easy way to count uppercase words within a string?

Comment: Thanks alot! This worked for me:
function countUppercase($str){
      preg_match_all("/\b[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+\b/",$str,$matches);
      return count($matches[0]);
}

Comment: This question is Too Broad / Unclear because there is no coding attempt, no sample input, no expected output, no context, no proof of research.  Because the wording of this question is somewhat ambiguous, there posted answers that perform differing actions - this is not good for researchers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shooting from the hip, but this (or something like it) should work:

```
function countUppercase($string) {
     return preg_match_all(/\b[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+\b/, $string)
}

countUppercase("Hello good Sir"); // 2
```

Comment: Sorry about all the edits; I've been programming in Python all morning and made a bunch of syntax errors.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a regular expression to find all uppercase words and count them:

```
echo preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z]+\b/', $str);
```

The expression `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) so it will only match whole uppercase words.

Comment: should the digits also be in that character class, [A-Z0-9]. CAPS123 looks uppercase!

Comment: Simplified it since `preg_match_all` does already return the number of matches.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function upper_count($str)
{
    $words = explode(" ", $str);
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        if (strtoupper($word) === $word)
        {
            $i++;
        }
    }

    return $i;
}

echo upper_count("There ARE two WORDS in upper case in this string.");
?>
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

This would count the number of uppercase within a string, even for a string that include non-alphanumeric characters

```
function countUppercase($str){ 
     preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/",$str,$matches); 
     return count($matches[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to strip all non-uppercase letters with **preg_replace** and then count the return string with **strlen** like so:

```
function countUppercase($string) {
    echo strlen(preg_replace("/[^A-Z]/","", $string));
}

echo countUppercase("Hello and Good Day"); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = <<<A
ONE two THREE four five Six SEVEN eighT
A;
$count=0;
$s = explode(" ",$str);
foreach ($s as $k){
    if( strtoupper($k) === $k){
        $count+=1;
    }
}
```