# PHP: How to convert a string that contains upper case characters

Tags: php, string

i'm working on class names and i need to check if there is any upper camel case name and break it this way:

```
 "UserManagement" becomes "user-management"
```

or

```
 "SiteContentManagement" becomes "site-content-management"
```

after extensive search i only found various use of ucfirst, strtolower,strtoupper, ucword and i can't see how to use them to suit my needs any ideas?

thanks for reading ;)

Comment: Try these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211875/check-if-a-string-is-all-caps-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182013/php-count-uppercase-words-in-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814880/how-to-check-if-letter-is-upper-or-lower-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) to replace any instance of a lowercase letter followed with an uppercase with your lower-dash-lower variant:

```
$dashedName = preg_replace('/([^A-Z-])([A-Z])/', '$1-$2', $className);
```

Then followed by a [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/strtolower) to take care of any remaining uppercase letters:

```
return strtolower($dashedName);
```

The full function here:

```
function camel2dashed($className) {
  return strtolower(preg_replace('/([^A-Z-])([A-Z])/', '$1-$2', $className));
}
```

---

To explain the regular expression used:

```
/        Opening delimiter
(        Start Capture Group 1
  [^A-Z-]   Character Class: Any character NOT an uppercase letter and not a dash
)        End Capture Group 1
(        Start Capture Group 2
  [A-Z]    Character Class: Any uppercase letter
)        End Capture Group 2
/        Closing delimiter
```

As for the replacement string

```
$1  Insert Capture Group 1
-   Literal: dash
$2  Insert Capture Group 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Theres no built in way to do it.

This will `ConvertThis` into `convert-this`:

```
$str = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1-$2', $str);
$str = strtolower($str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to get each words, then add the dashes like this:

```
preg_match_all ('/[A-Z][a-z]+/', $className, $matches); // get each camelCase words
$newName = strtolower(implode('-', $matches[0])); // add the dashes and lowercase the result
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply done without any capture groups -- just find the zero-width position before an uppercase letter (excluding the first letter of the string), then replace it with a hyphen, then call strtolower on the new string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fijOP))

```
echo strtolower(preg_replace('~(?!^)(?=[A-Z])~', '-', $string));
```

The lookahead `(?=...)` makes the match but doesn't consume any characters.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do that might be preg_replace using a pattern that replaces uppercase letters with their lowercase counterparts adding a "-" before them.

You could also go through each letter and rebuild the whole string.